# ¿Como añadir coordenadas de forma dinamica a una variable Json?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic

Necesito que en la variable `var points`, la primera coordenada `lat: -2.45645, lng: 1.5465` los datos sean del evento `center_changed` y la segunda coordenada `lat: -3.6546, lng: 12.165` los datos provengan de la función `$scope.centerOnMe` o de los marcadores que los guardo en un `$scope.array_marcadores = [];`.

```
angular.module('ei.exampleG', ['pascalprecht.translate'])
.controller('exampleGCtrl', ['$scope', '$ionicLoading', 'mapLoc', function ($scope, $ionicLoading, mapLoc ) {

    var points = [
            {
                lat: -2.45645,
                lng: 1.5465
            },
            {
                lat: -3.6546,
                lng: 12.165
            }
    ],
        sel_point = 0;

    var mapOptions = {
        center: points[sel_point],
        scrollwheel: true,
        zoom: cerca,
        zoomControl: true,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var eldiv = document.getElementById('MyMap');
    var cerca = 4

    function initialize() {
          map = new google.maps.Map(eldiv, mapOptions);

    var easingAnimator = EasingAnimator.makeFromCallback(function (latLng) {
        map.setCenter(latLng)
    });

    Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll('.map_keep__button'))
            .map(function (dom_elem, i) {
                dom_elem.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                    var point = map.getCenter();
                    easingAnimator.easeProp({
                        lat: point.lat(),
                        lng: point.lng()
                    }, points[i]);
                });
            });
        $scope.map = map;
    };

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

      $scope.centerOnMe = function () {
        if (!$scope.map) {
            return;
        }
        mapLoc.getLatLong().then(
            function (latLong) {
                $scope.foundLat = latLong.lat;
                $scope.foundLng = latLong.long;
            },
            function (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        )
    };

}]);
```

En el archivo ejemplo.html el `<div class="map_keep__button"> To point 1 </div>` es el encargado de tener el evento al hacer click en el y direcciona hacia la primera coordenada,  `<div class="map_keep__button"> To point 2 </div>` direcciona a la segunda coordenada. Solo quiero tener un `<div>` que me direccione a la segunda coordenada

```
    <div id="MyMap" class="map"></div>
    <div ng-click="centerOnMe();" class="button button-icon ion-android-locate botonFind"></div>
    <div class="map_keep__button_list">
        <div class="map_keep__button">
            TO point1
        </div>
        <div class="map_keep__button">
            TO point2
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: ¿Y qué problema tienes o cual es el error? ¿Los comentarios en inglés son porque estás copiando algo que encontraste en otro sitio y no te funciona? Aclara un poco a qué te estás enfrentando. Usa esta guía: [mcve].

Comment: el problema esta en que esta variable.  var points = [
            {
                lat: 16.156,
               lng: 17.4564
            },
            {
                lat: 89.4646,
                lng: 4.498484
            }
    ],

Comment: Edita tu pregunta siguiendo esta guía [mcve]. Gracias.

Comment: Podrías dibujar lo que quieres lograr y en dónde te da problemas?

Comment: Dibujar en un papel y subir la imagen?

Comment: así es porque le doy vueltas a la pregunta y sigo sin entender, quizás mediante un gráfico pueda entender mejor. Saludos :D

Comment: dejo este enlace [http://codepen.io/ErDmKo/pen/Jdpmzv] para que mas o menos tengas la idea, en el ejemplo, solo existe dos coordenadas para hacer un slider entre ellas

Comment: En ese enlace (http://codepen.io/ErDmKo/pen/Jdpmzv) ambos botones funcionan, pero tú dices: "quiero un div que me direccione a la segunda coordenada". ¿Quieres decir "quiero un div que centre el mapa en mi posición"?

Comment: No quiero tener coordenadas fijas sino una funcion para obtenerlas de manera dinamica, ya sea de una base de datos que tenga, y con una lista que ya la tengo implementada, poder recibir esas coordenadas y centrar el mapa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres recuperar las coordenadas de una base de datos, api, etc. tienes que hacerlo primero mediante un servicio.

Es decir crear un service en tu proyecto que realice la comunicación con esa BD y traiga la información.

Después desde tu controlador llamarás a esa función del servicio y obtendrás los datos que los podrás almacenar donde quieras. En este caso por lo que comentas en el $scope que almacena las coordenadas.

Aquí tienes código de ejemplo de lo que te estoy hablando. [Enlace](http://java-white-box.blogspot.com.es/2015/06/angularjs-servicio-tipo-service-crear.html)